# Why won't this django-rest-swagger API documentation display/work properly?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I've built a Django API that when given an email address via POST will respond with a boolean value indicating weather or not that email address already exists in my database:

```
class isEmailTaken(views.APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny,]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            email = request.DATA['email']
        except KeyError:
            return HttpResponse(
                'An email was not given with this request.',
                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            )
        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(
                User.objects.filter(email=email),
                content_type="application/json",
                status=status.HTTP_200_OK,
            )
        )
```

Now I would like to use the [**django-rest-swagger**](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger/) package to automatically generate documentation for this API. I installed the package and inserted the comments you see above between the triple-quotes. When I look at the documentation produced by django-rest-swagger for this API, I see the image below.

[image]

However, when I click the `Try it out!` button, I get the error shown below. Notably, it never gives me a chance to input the email argument that it should send via POST.

[image]

Why doesn't the Django-Swagger-Package create docs that allow me to properly the argument "email" via POST? How do I make this work?

Comment: To the two down-voters: How is this question unclear or un-useful? Why would you say that it shows a lack of research. I've explained what I tried to do. The software doesn't seem to work as advertised and I'm asking why. Seems like a completely legitimate question that StackOverflow was created for.

Comment: Can you print out the request and the request.DATA objects just before the return statement so we might see, what's going on here?

Comment: Norman, I have edited the original question to include two new log statements. You can see the output here: https://gist.github.com/syedsaqibali/b2f825c8234df77a9e7a

Comment: I edited the original question so that it includes Norman's solution and focuses on the still-outstanding portion of the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I tested this with `cigar_example` which is made by django-rest-swagger and in that example they written one [custom view](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger/blob/master/cigar_example/cigar_example/restapi/views.py#L75) which is also not rendering input parameters

Lastly i look into source code and found that django-rest-swagger needs `get_serializer_class` to build body parameters

So it worked with the following code:

```
class isEmailTaken(views.APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny,]
    serializer_class = IsEmailTakenSerializer

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return self.serializer_class

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            email = request.DATA['email']
        except KeyError:
            return HttpResponse(
               'An email was not given with this request.', 
                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            )
        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(
                User.objects.filter(email=email), 
                content_type="application/json",
                status=status.HTTP_200_OK,
             )
         )
```

and `IsEmailTakenSerializer`:

```
from rest_framework import serializers


class IsEmailTakenSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
```

Comment: Thanks Venkatesh! I'll give this a try in the next 12 hours. Assuming it works (and I think it will) I'll give you the bounty points at that time.

Comment: This gave the error: name 'fields' is not defined in IsEmailTakenSerializer. Is there a typo here?

Comment: Worked! Thanks Venkatesh. Bounty Awarded.

Comment: @VenkateshBachu first of all thanks for clearing the doubts, but  still  request body is not visible in swagger UI. Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

django-rest-swagger tries to send a POST request without some data.

First you have to fix your view like this:

```
from rest_framework import status
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        email = request.DATA['email']
    except KeyError:
        return HttpResponse(
            'An email was not given with this request.', 
            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
        )
    return HttpResponse(
        json.dumps(
            User.objects.filter(email=email), 
            content_type="application/json",
            status=status.HTTP_200_OK,
        )
    )
```

If you try this, you should see your nice error message now.

Next step is to look at django-rest-swagger docs to find out what to do that it renders a html form field right above the "Try it out" button.

Comment: That defintely helps a bit. Thanks.

Comment: I edited the original question so that it includes Norman's solution and focuses on the still-outstanding portion of the question.