# DRF 3.6: How to document input parameters in APIView (for automatic doc generation)?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm struggling with [DRF 3.6 auto-generated interactive documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/documenting-your-api/#built-in-api-documentation) to provide input parameters to fill in interactive mode.

As a result, I get an empty windows for my POST request (which would require 3 parameters actually):

[image]

With Swagger, I could do it directly in docstring with some YAML.
Now, after browsing DRF documentation, I can't find the way to do it.

```
class ActivateCustomerView(APIView):

    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request):
        """ View dedicated to activating a pre-recorded customer 
            # Should I add some parameters here?
        """

        serializer = ActivateCustomerSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        # ...
```

Answer (score 9):

I Got the answer from Tom Christie:

`serializer_class` by itself isn't enough - the view needs to implement get_serializer, see: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/schemas.py#L570

So in My case, adding this works well:

```
def get_serializer(self):
    return ActivateCustomerSerializer()
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I forgot to answer regarding the input parameters. I believe that would be based on the serializer. Have you tried specifying your `serializer_class`?

With DRF's inbuilt documentation generator, you'd want to put your docstrings on the class level and include the request method as such:

```
class ActivateCustomerView(APIView):
    """
    post:
    View dedicated to activating a pre-recorded customer 
    # Should I add some parameters here?

    # if you have a get request
    get:
    # your docs for the get handler
    """

    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request):

        serializer = ActivateCustomerSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        # ...
```

Comment: it seems `serializer_class` attribute works for generic api views only. Plus, I could not use a serializer at all and would need to set input parameters anyway.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `APIView` over [`GenericAPIView`](http://www.cdrf.co/3.6/rest_framework.generics/GenericAPIView.html)? Also, if my understanding of the purpose of your view is correct, perhaps you might want to take a look at [`UpdateAPIView`](http://www.cdrf.co/3.6/rest_framework.generics/UpdateAPIView.html) and overriding the `patch` method

Comment: No the APIView is on purpose here.

Comment: this might be relevant for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25752983/why-wont-this-django-rest-swagger-api-documentation-display-work-properly

Comment: nope, it doesn't work unfortunately. But it was expected since the solution was related to swagger.

Comment: @ThomasJiang did you get any solution for this problem?